# Python static variable in function global name not defined

Tags: python

I have written a function to calculate the heading between two points only if a vehicle reports that it's moving and that the vehicle has moved 20cm between points.

The function uses static variables - or at least it would if it worked - to keep track of previous positions and heading values.

Here is the code:

```
def withCan(pos):

    eastdist = pos[0]-previous_pos[0]
    northdist = pos[1]-previous_pos[1]
    canflag = pos[2]

    if (canflag == 1 or canflag==2):

        if (previous_canflag == 1 and canflag == 2):
            previous_heading += 180.0
            previous_canflag = canflag
        elif (previous_canflag == 2 and canflag == 1):
            previous_heading += 180.0
            previous_canflag = canflag
        else:
            previous_canflag = canflag

    if ( (canflag == 1 or canflag == 2) and math.sqrt(northdist*northdist+eastdist*eastdist) > canstep ): 
        previous_heading = math.degrees(math.atan2(eastdist, northdist))
        previous_pos[0] = pos[0]
        previous_pos[1] = pos[1]

    return previous_heading

withCan.previous_pos = [0.0,0.0]
withCan.previous_heading = 0.0
withCan.previous_canflag = 0
withCan.canstep = 0.2

positions = backandforth([100,100]) #populates an array of form [x,y,canflag]

for p in positions:
    print withCan(p)
```

I am getting an error that says `eastdist = pos[0]-previous_pos[0]
NameError: global name 'previous_pos' is not defined`. Please could someone explain the cause of this error?

Comment: The error message is quite clear - `global name 'previous_pos' is not defined`.

Comment: wow, i'm not a python expert, but i've never seen anyone declare variables like this `withCan.previous_pos = [0.0,0.0]`

Comment: @HaseebR7: It's legal Python. Such things are called function attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
def foo():
    pass

foo.name = 1
```

You are not creating a global name `name`. Instead you are adding a property to the `foo` function! You can access it with:

```
def foo():
    return foo.name

foo.name = 1
```

But that is quite weird. If you need a global name, just do it:

```
def foo():
    global name
    name += 1
    return name

name = 1
```

Remember that if you want to modify the global name from the function, you have to declare it as `global`. If you fail to do this, you can use it but you cannot assign to it.

Your confusion with static names may come from using classes. But note that in your code `withCan` is not a class, it is a plain function!

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could do `foo.name`. Feel like upvoting it 10 times.

Comment: @xyres: Yes, in Python you can add properties, just assigning, to almost anything. That is used by some frameworks to add metadata to functions and classes. And to implement static-like variables. But for normal user code and normal variables it may not be the best idea...

Comment: Encouraging people to write to globals when it's not absolutely necessary (and it rarely is) is probably not the best idea, either. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you are trying to do is writing a class...

```
class WithCan():
    def __init(self, previous_pos)__:
        self.previous_pos=previous_pos

    def withCan(self, pos):
        # your function as class method
```

Then you could initialize an instance

```
withCan=WithCan(previous_pos)
```

and access it

```
withCan.previous_pos=...
```

Comment: And _this_ is the only sane answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do static variables in Python using function attributes, but you need to use the full name inside the function to access those attributes.

Here's a short demo.

```
def test(a):
    print a, a + test.b
    test.b += 1

test.b = 5
test(3)
test(10)
```

**output**

```
3 8
10 16
```

However, it would be more usual to do this sort of thing using a class, as shown in Tim's answer.

Another way to do statics in Python is to give your function default mutable arguments, but many people are uncomfortable with that. But if you're curious, please see [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Answer (score 0):

Let me contribute a perhaps more streamlined way of *emulating* static variables in functions that could make the OP's example maybe easier to read:

```
def with_can(pos):
  if not hasattr(with_can, "canflag"):
    # set up and initialise the static variables
    with_can.canflag = 0
    with_can.previous_pos = [0.0,0.0]
    with_can.previous_heading = 0.0
    with_can.canstep = 0.2

  # ... use them ...
  eastdist = pos[0]-with_can.previous_pos[0]
  # ... etc ...
```

Basically at the first invocation we detect that one of the "static" variables (`canflag`) is not yet there so we add and initialise all of them. After that they can be used as indicated.

However, as others have pointed out already, it is much better to write a class with data members instead of these "static" function variables.